# How to generate Excel graphs with Groovy

Tags: excel, groovy, graph, automation

Using Groovy, how does one automate the creation of a chart in Excel using a text file as the source of data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to script Excel files with Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057870/how-to-script-excel-files-with-groovy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have have used Guillaume Laforge's Scriptom API for using Groovy to call into MS Office applications.  If you install Groovy via the Windows installer and have Excel installed on the same machine you should be able to do a fair bit with Scriptom -> http://groovy.codehaus.org/COM+Scripting.