# How to script Excel files with Groovy

Tags: excel, groovy, plot

I want to create excel files in Groovy, then have them plotted.  This code was taken from an example using Microsoft's Shell Scripting language:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objWorksheet.Cells(1,1) = "Operating System"
objWorksheet.Cells(2,1) = "Windows Server 2003"
objWorksheet.Cells(3,1) = "Windows XP"
objWorksheet.Cells(5,1) = "Windows NT 4.0"
objWorksheet.Cells(6,1) = "Other"

objWorksheet.Cells(1,2) = "Number of Computers"
objWorksheet.Cells(2,2) = 145
objWorksheet.Cells(3,2) = 987
objWorksheet.Cells(4,2) = 611
objWorksheet.Cells(5,2) = 41
objWorksheet.Cells(6,2) = 56

Set objRange = objWorksheet.UsedRange
objRange.Select

Set colCharts = objExcel.Charts
colCharts.Add()

Set objChart = colCharts(1)
objChart.Activate

objChart.HasLegend = FALSE
objChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Operating System Use"
```

How would I modify this to work in Groovy?

Comment: As Tim pointed out, POI doesn't support charts, so never mind.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need groovy to work with [COM](http://groovy.codehaus.org/COM+Scripting).  Towards the bottom of this [page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scriptom+1.2) is an example of automating Excel.

**EDITS**

Here's your example translated into Groovy (I ran this under Groovy 1.8.2):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.tlb.office.excel.XlChartType
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.tlb.office.excel.XlRowCol
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.tlb.office.excel.XlChartLocation

// create a xls instance
def xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")

xls.Visible = true

Thread.sleep(1000)

// get the workbooks object
def workbooks = xls.Workbooks
// add a new workbook
def workbook  = workbooks.Add()

// select the active sheet
def sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

cell = sheet.Range("A1")
cell.Value = "Operating System"
cell = sheet.Range("A2")
cell.Value = "Windows Server 2003"
cell = sheet.Range("A3")
cell.Value = "Windows XP"
cell = sheet.Range("A4")
cell.Value = "Windows NT 4.0"
cell = sheet.Range("A5")
cell.Value = "Other"

cell = sheet.Range("B1")
cell.Value = "Number of Computers"
cell = sheet.Range("B2")
cell.Value = 145
cell = sheet.Range("B3")
cell.Value = 987
cell = sheet.Range("B4")
cell.Value = 611
cell = sheet.Range("B5")
cell.Value = 41

def chart = workbook.Charts.Add(Scriptom.MISSING, sheet)  // create chart object
chart.ChartType = XlChartType.xl3DArea // set type to pie
chart.SetSourceData(sheet.Range("A1:B5"), XlRowCol.xlColumns) // set source data
chart.Location(XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet) // add chart as new sheet
```

Comment: Thanks.  That looks complicated for a beginner!  Any suggestions as to where to start?

Comment: @blaughi, it is not too complicated.  I translated your sample code above into Groovy.  It mapped pretty direct.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much.  Reverse engineering this is helping me understand Groovy, and coding in general.  The example on the page you linked seems incomplete.  They use `ActiveXProxy`, not `ActiveXObject`, which I don't get.  This is great.  I would buy you coffee if you would add more comments to describe what's happening in each block of code (specifically aftter the last `cell.Value` definition.

Comment: @blaughi, I added some comments for you.  I believe that the "ActiveXProxy" was for an older version of the scriptom library

Comment: How would I create an Area Chart, as opposed to a Column chart?  Seems more involved...

Comment: @blaughi, see new code sample.  Note that I had to more explicitly define and create the chart to be able to modify the type.

Answer (score 2):

Mark's answer above was a great example.  It's event easier to follow if you make a couple simple changes:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.tlb.office.excel.*

def xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")

xls.Visible = true

Thread.sleep(1000)

// add a new workbook
def workbook  = xls.Workbooks.Add()

// select the active sheet
def sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet    

sheet.Range("A1").Value = "Operating System"
sheet.Range("A2").Value = "Windows Server 2003"
sheet.Range("A3").Value = "Windows XP"
sheet.Range("A4").Value = "Windows NT 4.0"
sheet.Range("A5").Value = "Other"

sheet.Range("B1").Value = "Number of Computers"
sheet.Range("B2").Value = 145
sheet.Range("B3").Value = 987
sheet.Range("B4").Value = 611
sheet.Range("B5").Value = 41

def chart = workbook.Charts.Add(Scriptom.MISSING, sheet)  // create chart object
chart.ChartType = XlChartType.xl3DArea // set type to pie
chart.SetSourceData(sheet.Range("A1:B5"), XlRowCol.xlColumns) // set source data
chart.Location(XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet) // add chart as new sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option *may* be [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html), depending on what all you need to actually implement.

Either option will be complicated for a beginner; the easy path would be to use the shell.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the shell"?  Oh you mean the MS shell?

Comment: @blaughli Yep. The COM approach might be easier than POI if you're on a Windows box, though.

Comment: @tim_yates I'm not either. No, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I would also go for [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). A working example can be found at the [busy developer guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook). There is also [GSheets](https://github.com/andresteingress/gsheets), a thin groovy wrapper for Apache POI, see the [blog post](http://blog.andresteingress.com/2012/01/13/gsheets-a-groovy-builder-based-on-apache-poi/) and the [unit test](https://github.com/andresteingress/gsheets/blob/master/src/test/groovy/org/gsheets/ExcelFileTests.groovy) for an example usage.

Answer (score 0):

Probably simplest (in terms of external code) is text format, cells are delimited by '\t' and lines "\r\n".
Be careful on cell having sense String but with num characters (or Date-alike), best to prepend with single apostrophe

Such format can be pasted by clipboard or open from file menu.